# knitr doest recognise installed packages, though no problems running chunks individually

Tags: r-markdown

I'm having problems knitting an R markdown document. the particular chunk that's giving mt trouble uses the "tableone" package, and gives the following error:

> "Error in library(tableone): there is no package called 'tableone' "

the code chunk is (if necessary i'll upload some of the the actual data):

```
>pt.table1<-patient.table[,-unwanted.cols]%>%tbl_df()
>catVars<-pt.table1[sapply(pt.table1,class)=="integer"]%>%colnames()
>my.tab2<-CreateTableOne(data = pt.table1,strata = 
>"cerebrovascular.pt",factorVars = catVars)
>print(my.tab2)
>summary(my.tab2)
```

this package is properly installed,and the chunk works fine if I just run it by itself (such as with CTRL ALT C), and of course it works when ran through the console.

I have a similar problem inn a different chunk with package 'e1071'.
other packages in the rest of the code chunks work fine.